# Im having trouble with changing the value of button

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
async function invoiceToHTMLRow(invoice) {
  // let balance = await Balance(Invoice.invoiceNo)
  //   console.log('this',balance)
    return `<tr> 
<td> ${invoice.customerId} </td>
<td id ='invNo'> ${invoice.invoiceNo} </td>
                 <td> ${invoice.amount} </td>
                  <td> ${invoice.customerName} </td>
                  <td> ${invoice.invoiceDate} </td>
                  <td> ${invoice.dueDate} </td>
                  <td> ${await Balance(invoice.invoiceNo)} </td>     
    </td>
                 <td>
                     <i class = "fa-Balance"onclick="showBalance('${invoice.invoiceNo}')" > Balance </i>

<i class = "fa-fa-edit"onclick="updateInvoice('${invoice.invoiceNo}')" > Edit </i>
<i class="fa-trash" onclick="deleteInvoiceFromTable('${invoice.invoiceNo}')"> Delete </i>
</td>
   </tr>`
    async function showBalance(invoiceNo) {
        const invoice = await repo.getInvoiceByNo(parseInt(invoiceNo))
        const number = document.querySelector('#invNo').value = invoice.invoiceNo
        const BTN =  document.getElementById('balanceBtn');
        BTN.innerHTML = `${await Balance(number)}` 
    }
```

so on my html page i get 3 balance buttons but when i click on one of them the value of the first button changes even if i clicked on the other ones   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Az79C.png
how to target the button that i clicked on?
ty

Comment: In the code shown there's only one "button".  When you create more "buttons", are you re-using the same `id`?  Because that could certainly cause this behavior.

Comment: Share your HTML code snippet where the buttons are

Comment: @David im using a loop that keeps on creating the same button multiple times so they all share the same id

Comment: I agree with @David. I bet you're using the same id for all three buttons.

Comment: You should add a number with the id to make them unique. Use loop counter for the number.

Comment: @justanotherguy yes im using the same ID for all the balance buttons because im using a loop that creates this button everytime i get a new Invoice (the data im using here). So how do I specify the button that i clicked on

Comment: Could you share your entire HTML code that has all of the buttons so we could see? @Sul6an

Comment: @justanotherguy I added it

Comment: I'm assuming you are generating the buttons dynamically, so you should do the same thing for your id's. That way you can make sure the id's are unique and at the same time you can pass the id you generate to your update and delete function.